# Component taking too long to respond Angular

Tags: angular

One of feature module taking so long to respond. it taking 20 ms to load that feature module.
there are more than 27 components and some external libraries like

- NgSelectModule,
- NgxEditorModule
- MultiSelectModule,
- NgxMaskModule

other 27 components. Module has many functionality and inner level

[image: Network tracking]

I have tried using standalone module newly introduced in v14 but no luck as this is a eager loaded component at end.

Suggest me with better solution folks.

Comment: Do more lazy loading. 27 components is quite big

Comment: Its a `standalone component` not `standalone module`. It is unclear, we can not guess what could be the solution unless you clearly state the problem with sufficient information. Please update the question with more details, perhaps add module code before and after migration to `standalone components`

Comment: thanks @Indraraj26 adding more lazy loaded module did it

Answer (score 0):

I would try to preload the lazy loaded module. This should improve the load performance when you actually go to the route that loads it.

```
{
  path: 'lazy-module-path',
  loadChildren: () => import('./my-lazy-module.module').then(mod => mod.BigFeatureModule),
  data: { preload: true }
},
```

You can also preload all of them if you want/need to:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { 
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
)
```

Comment: this is too usefull